# View url rules to get proper url

Tags: php

Take this link for example: http://example.com/p/12345

The `12345` part of the URL is a variable.

It should display like `?something=12345` but it doesnt so they are obviously using url rules/rematch. How do I view what the URL would be without the rules?

For example it might be something like http://example.com/p?number=12345

Comment: I hope it will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Comment: @Mr.Developer thank but im not asking how to do it. If a website has used url-rewriting how do I view the **original** url

Comment: is this on your own site? If YES - read through  the `.htaccess` file, if NO you can try guessing the parameter name

Comment: @RamRaider oh i see, so there isnt like a way to actually view it without guessing

Comment: not as far as I'm aware there isn't - afterall this mechanism helps developers/webmasters obfuscate parameters to begin with

Answer (score 1):

In a word, you can't. Unless you operate the web site and have access to the .htaccess file that is rewriting the URLs you can not determine exactly where it is being redirected.

In your example both the p and the 12345 could be variable.